Does my AC vent air from the room to outside?
I have an AC unit that has a fan and logic in a unit mounted to the wall, and a box outside that blows air through the condenser(?)  Will air from the room be vented outside?  If I were brewing beer or doing something else that might produce a strong smell would it be vented out and make outside smell?

no it does not do that, it would be a terrible waste of energy, exhausting cool air to outside

how would air get from inside unit to the outside unit?

Smells generated inside the house can get out via the clothes dryer vent when the dryer is running, the exhaust fan over the stove and from the bathroom exhaust fans. It is very unlikely that your AC unit would vent to the outside, but we need to know what are make and model of your AC unit.

@Traveler It is a waste of energy, but a lot of AC units work that way for convenience. Basically all portable units do it. Probably the unit the OP describes does not work that way, but there is no way to no for sure without knowing the model.

@Traveler It may be a "terrible waste of energy" but not having enough fresh air is terrible for your health. ASHRAE 62.1 and 62.2 tell you how much air exchange you need, and better units, particularly PTACs, have ventilation systems.

No ordinary residential split or minisplit a/c unit does any venting of inside air to the outside. There are two separate air circulation loops and they are not connected.
Inside air at the inside temperature is pulled into the inside unit by the "air handler" fan, circulated through the cold "evaporator" coil (having its temperature lowered by about twelve to fifteen deg F), and then pushed back inside. None of this air is directed outside by the a/c unit.
Outside air at ambient outside temperature is pulled through the hot coil in the outside (condensing) unit (absorbing heat from the coil) and then at a temperature well above ambient is pushed back outside by the condensing unit fan. None of this air is directed inside.
Some well designed modern houses do have an air exchange system with energy recovery, but AFIK this is separate from the HVAC machinery.

Window units often have (or at least had) a mode that does some minor air exchange. Split units can't.

Would these window units bring in outside air or would they pump inside air out? Would these units that do this be "ordinary" or would they be special? (I upvoted your comment because I appreciate being corrected when I am wrong.)

It was a fairly common feature, especially when more people smoked. The ones I've seen would use Venturi flow to draw in air from outside, counting on the house not being sealed so well that active exhaust was required to balance this. A panel could be opened or closed up control  this. I don't know if this feature (commonly labelled "vent") persists in modern units.

Edited my answer and deleted my comment to make it refer  only to ordinary split and mini-split systems which seems to be what the OP's question is directed toward..

This sounds like a "split sytem". two parts with a trunking running between them.
These do not provide ventilation, only cooling, dehumidifying, and in many cases heating.
If it is a box mounted through the wall (or a window opening) with part inside and part outside then these may provide ventilation

Let me first explain to you how a split-system air conditioning system works:

The indoor unit draws in air from the room, passes it over the cold evaporator coil, and blows the cooled air back into the room.
The outdoor unit contains the compressor and condenser oil. It takes the hot air from the indoor unit and blows it through the condenser coil, dissipating the heat outside.

So, theoretically, the air room from the room is not directly vented outside. The only thing that goes outside is the heat that was absorbed from the room.
However, your concern about strong smells is valid. If the indoor unit is drawing in air from a room with strong odor, some of that smell could get expelled outside through the outdoor unit. This is because the refrigeration cycle requires a small amount of air to be vented to the outside in order to maintain proper pressure.
So, to answer your question, some of the indoor air, including any strong odors, could get expelled to the outside through the outdoor unit.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

-1 The refrigeration cycle is a closed loop of refrigerant. The refrigerant flows in tubing between the indoor and outdoor units. No "small amount of air" involved. No "hot air from the indoor unit".

Sounds like a ChatGPT hallucination
